# Homeomorphism between open unit ball and $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $B=\{x\in\mathbb R^n : ||x||<1\}$ the open unit ball with the subapce topology of $\mathbb R^n$. I want to show that $B^n\cong\mathbb R^n$ with the map $F(x)=\tan(\frac{\pi ||x||}{2})\frac{x}{||x||}$ for $x\not=0$ and $F(0)=0$

Well $\frac{x}{||x||}$ is more or less the direction of the vector $x$, the norm is a number out of $[0,1)$ and the scaled tangent is a Homeomorphism from $[0,1)$ to the positive real numbers.

I want to show that $F(x)$ is contionous, bijective and there is an inverse map.

**Injectivity**: Let $F(x)=F(y)\leftrightarrow ||F(x)||=||F(y)||\leftrightarrow \tan(\frac{\pi ||x||}{2})||\frac{x}{||x||}||=\tan(\frac{\pi ||y||}{2})||\frac{y}{||y||}||$

I know that the tangent is injective but I do not see how $x=y$ can be followed.

**Surjectivity**: Let $y\in\mathbb R^n$, now I need to show $\exists x\in B^n: F(x)=y$, i.e $\tan(\frac{\pi ||x||}{2})\frac{x}{||x||}=y$ I do not see how surjectivity can be followed form this.

**Inverse map**: I know that the tangent has an inverse map, namely the arctangent, but how can this be used here?

**Continuity**: Well I know that the tangent is only contin. on $\mathbb R\setminus\{(n+\frac{1}{2})\pi: n\in \mathbb Z\}$

Comment: Your map works fine. For example for your beginning argument for injectivity, the two norms on the right of the tangents are each $1$ so after cancelling that and using injectivity of tangent you have $||x||=||y||$. Then since as you say the map preserves rays through the origin you have $x=y$.

Comment: babla da fatiye dichho toh!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Injectivity

$F(x)=F(y)$, with $x\ne0$ and $y\ne0$ means

$$
\tan\biggl(\frac{\pi \|x\|}{2}\biggr)\frac{x}{\|x\|}=
\tan\biggl(\frac{\pi \|y\|}{2}\biggr)\frac{y}{\|y\|}
$$

So we can assume $x\ne0$ and $y\ne0$. Then, taking norms, 
$$
\tan\biggl(\frac{\pi \|x\|}{2}\biggr)=\tan\biggl(\frac{\pi \|y\|}{2}\biggr)
$$
because $x/\|x\|$ has norm $1$ and the same for $y/\|y\|$; moreover $\tan t>0$ if $t>0$. By the injectivity of the tangent you get
$$
\frac{\pi \|x\|}{2}=\frac{\pi \|y\|}{2}
$$
so $\|x\|=\|y\|$ and, finally $x=y$.

It's clear that $F(x)=0$ if and only if $x=0$, so the proof is complete.

#### Surjectivity

$0=F(0)$, so we only need to show that, for $z\ne0$, we can find $x$ with $F(x)=z$. We should have
$$
z=\tan\biggl(\frac{\pi \|x\|}{2}\biggr)\frac{x}{\|x\|}
$$
so
$$
\|z\|=\tan\biggl(\frac{\pi \|x\|}{2}\biggr)
$$
hence
$$
\frac{\pi\|x\|}{2}=\arctan\|z\|
$$
that is,
$$
\|x\|=\frac{2\arctan\|z\|}{\pi}.
$$
Thus the candidate is
$$
x=\frac{2\arctan\|z\|}{\pi\|z\|}z
$$
Verify it's the right one.

#### Continuity

The continuity of $F$ is obvious in the points different from $0$, because it's obtained by continuous functions. Since your domain consists of vectors with norm $<1$, there's no problem with the tangent function, because you consider only arguments in $(0,\pi/2)$. The continuity of the inverse is obvious as well 
outside $0$

Are $F$ and its inverse continuous at $0$?

A well known fact is that $\lim_{x\to0}F(x)=0$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to0}\|F(x)\|=0$; now
$$
\|F(x)\|=\biggl\|\tan\biggl(\frac{\pi\|x\|}{2}\biggr)\frac{x}{\|x\|}\biggr\|
=\tan\biggl(\frac{\pi\|x\|}{2}\biggr)
$$
that obviously satisfies the requested property. The same for the continuity at $0$ of $F^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I do not see why $x=\frac{2\arctan\|z\|}{\pi\|z\|}z$ should be unique (e.g the right one), isn't it possible to choose instead of $z/||z||$ something different, where the norm is equal to 1?. For continuity I set instead of $t$ $||x||$, but then $F(x)$ goes to $0$, independent if I come from left or right, is this ocrrect?

Comment: @Babla We're proving surjectivity, so finding one $x$ with $F(x)=z$ is sufficient. On the other hand, injectivity has already been proved, hasn't it? For continuity: that limit is $1$, so $\tan(\pi\|x\|/2)/\|x\|$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$. Hence...

Comment: Oh yes, you are right.Still, the continuity is not clear to me.

Comment: @Babla You can also use the fact that $\lim_{x\to0}F(x)=0$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to0}\|F(x)\|=0$.

Comment: Hmm, but $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} ||F(x)||=0$ is clear because $\tan(x)=0$ for $x\rightarrow 0$, therefore $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} F(x)=0$. Where do I need $\lim \frac{\tan t}{t}=1$ now?

Comment: I don't see why $||x||=||y|| \Rightarrow x=y$?

Comment: @Averroes2 The first equation (assumption that $F(x)=F(y)$) states that $\tan(\pi\|x\|/2)x/\|x\|=\tan(\pi\|y\|/2)y/\|y\|$. Once we have proved that $\|x\|=\|y\|$, it follow that $x=y$.

Comment: Yes, but the last step cannot follow immediately: For $n=1$ we have $|x|=|y|\Rightarrow x=y$ which is not true. Do I miss something?

Comment: @Averroes2 Sorry, but I don't understand the objection: $x$ and $y$ are not *any* vectors satisfying $\|x\|=\|y\|\ne0$; they have been chosen such that $\tan(\pi\|x\|/2)x/\|x\|=\tan(\pi\|y\|/2)y/\|y\|$ to begin with. Since we're able to prove that $\|x\|=\|y\|$, the terms $\tan(\pi\|x\|/2)=\tan(\pi\|x\|/2)$ cancel out and we have $x/\|x\|=y/\|y\|$. Again, the terms $\|x\|=\|y\|$ cancel out and we get $x=y$.

Comment: I think that we have here some implicit assumption not stated in the proof. I understand that these vectors have the same ray but how to state this formally?

Comment: @Averroes2 I want to prove that the function $F$ is injective, so I start with $F(x)=F(y)$ and draw conclusions.

Comment: OK, you last edit makes more sense to me. Thanks