# If $Y$ is a singleton, show that the space obtained from attaching an $n$-cell is $S^n$, hence $S^n=e^0 \cup e^n$ (disjoint union)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> If $Y$ is a singleton, show that the space obtained from attaching an $n$-cell is $S^n$, hence $S^n=e^0 \cup e^n$ (disjoint union)

I don't understand the last part of this.  This says that $S^2 = e^0 \cup e^2$, where $e^i$ is a homeomorphic copy of $D^i - S^{i-1}$.  That means $S^2 = e^0 \cup (D^2-S^{1})$.

But how can a sphere be the union of the interior of a disk and a point?

Comment: If you start with $S^2$ and take one point away then what remains (a sphere with a hole) is homeomorphic with an open disk $D^2-S^1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [stereographic projection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) .   So, the way I see it,  take away a point from the sphere, $S^2$ ,and you essentially have  $\mathbb R^2$.

More generally,  $\mathbb R^n \cup \infty =S^n $, the [one point compactification](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension).

Also,  in this connection, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/390722), for a homeomorphism between $D^n -S^{n-1} $ and $\mathbb R^n $...